# Power BI: Create a Manager of Manager column

Tags: powerbi

I feel like there is an easy solution that I just can't think of for this issue. I did look and wasn't able to find anything I felt would help.

I am trying to create a Director Column from the information below. I have an employee name column and a manager column.  You can see that Lenore is the manager for quite a few people and that James is Lenore's manager.
I'd like to create a column where it would show James's name where Lenore is the ManagerName.

[image: Lenore as Manager]

[image: Lenore's Manager]

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide,
Matt

Comment: To Clarify, there would be three columns:  PrefName, ManagerName, and DirectorName.  So it would go something like Jill, Lenore, James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create additional column using dax function PATH and PATHITEM.

https://dax.guide/path/

This function is used in tables that have some kind of internal hierarchy, to return the items that are related to the current row value. For example, in an Employees table that contains employees, the managers of employees, and the managers of the managers, you can return the path that connects an employee to his or her manager.